# how to find friends of friends in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

**Description :**

I have a table of users as following

students

```
id ------ name     
1  ------ John    
2  ------ Sarah    
3  ------ Peter
```

and friends table as

Buddies

```
person1 ------  person2    
1       ------  2
2       ------  3
```

Now I want all the friends of 2 and all other my friends whose friends are not my friends.

E.g in "people you may know" we see people that are friends of our friends but are not our friends

I have successfully written the query to find all my friends but I am not sure how to find "friends of my friends" in one query

Is there a way to do it in one query ....

I am finding friends like this

```
 select * from `students` join `buddy_circle` on 
'$reg_no' = `person_1` and `stregno` = `person_2` or 
'$reg_no' = `person_2` and `stregno` = `person_1`
```

where stregno is the id of student and buddy_circle is the friends table and `$regno` is the id of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?
I have tested it only with your example data.

```
select name from students where id in (
    select p2 from buddies where p1 in (
        select p2 from buddies where p1=[serach_for_id]));
```

Comment: That is correct ... its so short I thought it would be bigger ... but there is just one problem ... its is also returning me mutual friends ... know how to correct that ??

Comment: @RksRock to eliminate duplicates, `select distinct name ...`. BTW, this will probably perform poorly - you should [use joins instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26960392/256196)

Answer (score 1):

Join twice to get friends of friends:

```
select distinct name
from buddy_circle a
join buddy_circle b on b.p1 = a.p2
join students on id = b.p2
where a.p1 = $reg_no
```

Note the order of tables in the query is such that the where clause applies to the first named table and joined tables flow on from that, which gives maximum performance.

Comment: Your query works fine but its also returning the mutual friends of me and my friends ... how to avoid that ??

Comment: This query answers your question as stated (and especially as titled). Your comment is actually asking a different question with new/extra requirements: Please ask a new question with these new requirements (perhaps carrying over a working query from this question to start the new question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`select * from students As s
join buddy_circle As b on s.id= b.person_2 or b.person_1 = s.id
Where id =2`

This query should give you a list of all students what that have the same friend of 2.

If it work for you I will re-write it in a different format to make it even better

Comment: it returns the data of user "2" itself twice... and I want to get the friends of all my friends .. not a specific one ... @Mike

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work for you.
First I select Your friends in two first query.
Then I query the Buddies table (or Friends in this example) that they are friends of your friends
It covers all the situations:

```
/*select my friends in col2 while I'm in col1 */
SELECT p2 FROM Friends WHERE p1 = @MyID

UNION
/*select my friends in col1 while I'm in col 2 */
SELECT p1 FROM Friends WHERE P2 = @MyID

Union
/*
select my friend's friends which
my firends are in col1 and my firend's friends are in col2
*/
SELECT  p2 FROM Friends
WHERE
    p1 in (SELECT P2 FROM Friends where P1=@MyID)

union
SELECT p1 FROM Friends
WHERE
    p2 in (SELECT P2 FROM Friends where P1=@MyID)

union    
SELECT p1 FROM Friends
WHERE
    p2 in (SELECT P1 FROM Friends where P2=@MyID)

union
SELECT p2 FROM Friends
WHERE
    p1 in (SELECT P1 FROM Friends where P2=@MyID)
```

Comment: If it gives you repeated rows, just change the **Union ALL** to union

Comment: IT RETURNS MY THE DATA OF THE USER ITSELF ... THERE IS NOTHING AS FRIENDS OF FRIENDS IN THE RETURNED DATA